# socket program for windows

Tags: c++, winsock, serversocket

I am writing socket program for windows and trying to create communication between client and server. I am using select() api . But it is giving error as **ERROR: recvfrom unsuccessful**  Can anyone help me?

```
while(1)
{
    //memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    //blocks only for specified time
    status = select(0, &ReadSet, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (status == -1) 
    {
        extern int errno;
        cerr << "ERROR: Select unsuccessful: Error" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        cout << "ERRNO: " << _errno << endl;
    } 
    else if (status == 0) 
    {
        cout<<"Timeout occurred!  No data after 500ms" << endl; 
    } 
    else
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(clientSocket, &ReadSet)) 
        {
            // Receieve74.    
            numrcv = recv(clientSocket, buffer, MAXBUFLEN, NO_FLAGS_SET);  
            if (numrcv == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
               cerr << "ERROR: recvfrom unsuccessful" << endl;
            }
            // Print out receieved socket data92.   
            cout << "Message rcvd from client" << buffer<< endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to accept after select.

Comment: Or can we assume that clientSocket was received via a call to accept()? Is it TCP socket at all or UDP?

Comment: From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx), you can use WSAGetLastError() to get the last error code, right after recv() to get a more descriptive error code

Comment: To Aconcagua , Hi It is TCP socket